# Do I need to release my singleton object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, singleton

I have a singleton object in my app:

```
+ (id)shared {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedDownloadFirstData == nil)
            sharedDownloadFirstData = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedDownloadFirstData;
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

And I want to know if I need to realese it (I am not using ARC). To do that I am using:

```
[[DownloadFirstData shared] release];
```

Did I need to release this object? I have an array and other stuff in the object that I need to release.

Comment: If it's supposed to persist until the app ends, there's no need for an explicit release.  Although you may want to supply one just to make the analyzer happy.

Comment: why i don't need to release it? it have an auto release?

Comment: no, it haven't an autorelease (if you haven't put an autorelease). It will be killed when the app ends (just like all objects still in memory), so the memory is free.

Comment: You don't have to release it because it is going to live for the lifetime of the app.  You also shouldn't be doing retain.

Comment: @BrianNickel: `retain`ing from client code can be correct, because that code should not know or need to think about whether the object is a singleton and/or manages its own lifetime. It should follow the memory management rules, which say that `shared` returns a reference that might disappear at any time if not retained. In that case, of course, every `retain` must be balanced with a `release`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, you're right, but there should never be a case where you call release directly on another method call.  You would do the retain when you assign to a variable.

Comment: @BrianNickel: Yes, true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Objective-C, you should only ever call `release` on an object you own.  This typically means an object you've created with `alloc`, `init`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` or otherwise called `retain` on.  Here, the consumer of `[DownloadFirstData shared]` didn't call any of those functions and is not responsible for releasing it.  You will see this any time you call `[UIColor blackColor]`, for instance.

You may want to call `retain` on such an object, if you are crossing autorelease boundaries or are just not sure of the lifetime:

```
DownloadFirstData *local = [[DownloadFirstData shared] retain];
...
[local release];
```

In this case, you've taken ownership and are responsible for releasing.

But what about the definition of `shared`?  When you define a method not using `init`..., you are typically responsible for leaving with a release count of 0, with something like `[[self alloc] init] autorelease]`.  This is not the case for the singleton because your goal is for it to always exist and therefore always have a non-zero retain count.  You make this happen simply by not releasing it after you create it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no sense in having a singleton if you will release it.
Usually a singleton is created because you want the same object till the app ends.
At the end of your app life cycle all memory related to the app is freed.

Use a standard approach, if you need alloc release often.
if your singleton takes a lot of memory, you should consider to write it better.

anyway, [[DownloadFirstData shared] release]; will work.

Comment: Sending `release` will _work_, yes, but it's incorrect from an ownership POV: the singleton object owns itself. Really, your first sentence is the correct answer.

Comment: That should create a compiler warning or static analyzer error.  The name "shared" does not imply a transfer of ownership.

Comment: i just said that will work. not that it is correct to do that. :D

Comment: It will also likely crash the app the next time he tries referencing the disposed singleton.